# Autolayout Without UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have been looking around for a solution to this strange auto layout issue. I am trying to set up a paging UIScrollView with 5 pages. Each page has its own `container`, which is a generic UIView. My current setup looks like this:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] init];
container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *width =[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:container
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    relatedBy:0
    toItem:self.headlineView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *height =[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:container
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    relatedBy:0
    toItem:self.headlineView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
    multiplier:1.0
    constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:container
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:self.headlineView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
    multiplier:1.0f
    constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:container
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:self.headlineView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    multiplier:index
    constant:self.headlineView.frame.size.width];
[self.headlineView addSubview:container];
[self.headlineView addConstraints:@[width, height, top, left]];
```

**Context**: This is called within a for-loop that executes 5 times, where the variable `index` increments each time. That is working properly.

Based on the last constraint, I thought that this would give the desired effect. The multiplier each time (0-4) would move the left edge over by one unit of the scroll view's frame.

The actual result is quite strange. All 5 of the views are located on the second page of the scroll view, overlapping one another.

Are the multiplier and constant parameters not used like I thought they are? What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the view hasn't drawn the frame of `self.headlineView`. If you put an `NSLog(CGStringFromRect(self.headlineView.frame));` before you set the constraints I'd bet it'll be 0.

Try calling:

```
[view setNeedsLayout];
[view layoufIfNeeded];
```

... before you set the constraints, or try calling the constraint method inside of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of (presuming `viewDidLoad`?).

Comment: The frame is not 0. It has width and height members set already. Calling those two methods before the constraints does nothing.

Comment: Blat! Ok back to the drawing board

Comment: The issue seems to be that the `left` constraint is not doing what I think it would be. The other constraints work properly, but this last one seems to be the issue.

Comment: I think this is a bug. I found the issue.

Comment: Nope, not a bug. Just didn't read the documentation well enough :-]

Comment: Weird though, since if you set the constant to 0 and the multiplier to 2, it should actually be double the width; likewise if you set it to 0.5?

Comment: The multiplier does not actually pair with the constant. The documentation shows that the constant is just added at the end

Comment: But if the constant was 0, and the multiplier was 2, it should still be twice the width, no?

Comment: The multiplier was for the left edge, not the width. In a separate issue, I cannot use the width of the scroll view to determine its left edge. Auto layout is frustrating

Comment: Ah! Yes I see. Yeah, it's great when it works... Have you looked at Masonry? It's on github, makes programmatic constraints suck less.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Anything can make programmatic constraints less awful

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the multiplier and constant parameters do not do what I thought they do (or what they are intended to do).

My original layout put in the `index` as multiplier and the view width as the constant. However, it turns out I need to calculate it all for the constant parameter.

```
CGFloat offset = index * self.headlineView.frame.size.width;
NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:container
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:self.headlineView
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    multiplier:1.0f
    constant:offset];
```